# Normalize a complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra, scripting

I have a complex matrix say,

```
M={{a+bi,c,c,d},{0,a-di,c,d},{d,c,a-di,0},{d,c,c,a+bi}};
Normalize[M]
```

I attempted to normalize this symbolic matrix with Mathematica function `Normalize[M]` however it support only real matrices.  Is there another way of doing this? Can it be done numerically?

Comment: `Normalize[M, Norm]` works for me, though I think you need to replace the `i`s with `I`s in `M` (e.g. `M = {{a + b*I, c, c, d}, {0, a - d*I, c, d}, {d, c, a - d*I, 0}, {d, c, c, a + b*I}};`).

Comment: Normalizing a matrix can be ambiguous -- Divide by `Det[M]`, normalize row or column vectors. `Normalize[M, Det]` will do the former. `Normalize /@ M` normalizes rows. The `Norm` of a matrix is the largest singular value, so `Normalize[M, Norm]` will divide `M` by that.